# How to set Color of Dim Background for Dialog in Android Programmatically

Tags: android, dialog, android-theme

I want to change the Dim Background to blue or red, every example i've looked at used an XML file, but is there a way to set by just passing in a Color String?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is No direct way workaround but this may help you

Custom Dialog theme like this:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
 <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

windowNoTitle use to get rid from title bar. window backgroud is set to transparent windowIsFloating is false to expand dialog view to full screen.

**Custom Dialog.java**

```
public CustomDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
}
```

**custom_dialog.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dim_dialog_bg_color">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_root"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg_color"
        android:padding="16dp">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just to add,  you can programmatically set your layout of custom_dialog.xml. For example
using `dialog.setContentView(myLayout)` where myLayout is a View. Then with myLayout you add `myLayout.setBackground(Color.GREEN)` to change the Dim colour.

Answer (score 1):

change the style of the dialog and use it

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/red</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: How to change style Programmatically?

Comment: Dialog  yourDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme);

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
you can pass color code to ColorDrawable.

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: That's just setting the current window to a colour, not the dim color of the dialog

Comment: @nicko_yuan if your current window is dialog then it will set color to dialog